# How do I set up an anonymous autoversioning mod_dav_svn server?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-dav-svn

I would like to create a DAV SVN server with autoversioning that has no access control of any kind. I experimented with several variations on this, but every one of them runs into this error in the end:

```
"Anonymous lock creation is not allowed."
```

So, as a fallback option I would like to configure my SVN Location to have default credentials. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, and there may be a better way, but...

The [mod_auth_tkt](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/) module is a single sign-on solution for Apache.  You don't care about this for your application, but what is of interest is the support for "guest" logins.  For users without an authentication cookie (which for you will be all of them), you can assign a default identity.  The configuration would look something like this:

```
<Location /svn>
  AuthType None
  require valid-user
  TKTAuthGuestLogin on
  TKTAuthGuestUser guest
</Location>
```

This would authenticate everyone as the "guest" user, which ought to be make the DAV stuff happy.  **NB**: Completely untested!  I use `mod_auth_tkt` all the time, but I haven't tried this particular configuration.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  But works only if you have `TKTAuthSecret` set outside of the `Location` block.  (Apache 2.3.99).  If you do not need that secret (like in this case) something like `TKTAuthSecret -` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to give full access to your repository to ALL users, don't include security or authentication directives in your apache configuration.

If you're publishing your repository at www.example.com/svn, you may use something like this

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath "/path/to/your/svn" #filesystem path      
</Location>
```

Since authentication is disabled all commits will be done by the apache user (normally www-data or apache)

I hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: That was my original attempt. If you enable autoversioning on that location, however, you'll find that no, it is not going to work.